# Using Oracle XMLTABLE to get attribute value

Tags: oracle, xmltable

```
<PivotSet>
<item>
<column name = "B">A</column>
<column name ="SUM(A)">24</column>
</item>
<item>
<column name = "B">B</column>
<column name = "SUM(A)">15</column>
</item>
<item>
<column name = "B">C</column>
<column name = "SUM(A)">18</column>
</item>
<item>
<column name = "B">D</column>
<column name = "SUM(A)">21</column>
</item>
</PivotSet>
```

I have this XML column. Im trying to read the value A in the XML tag

```
<column name = "B">A</column>
```

Below SQL generates the above XML.

```
select xmlserialize(content t.B_XML) from t_aa
pivot xml(
sum(A) for B in (any)
) t;
```

Can you please help me with XMLTABLE SQL for this

Comment: Do you still have access to `t_aa` if so why not just query that directly? And do you mean attributes or values? Please show the exact output you are trying to get.

Comment: @AlexPoole - I want the data in pviot format. So I'm using PIVOT XML function in oracle and generating XML o/p. From that I'm trying to read the records via XMLTABLE function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from xmltable( '/PivotSet/item' passing xmltype('
<PivotSet>
<item>
<column name = "B">A</column>
<column name ="SUM(A)">24</column>
</item>
<item>
<column name = "B">B</column>
<column name = "SUM(A)">15</column>
</item>
<item>
<column name = "B">C</column>
<column name = "SUM(A)">18</column>
</item>
<item>
<column name = "B">D</column>
<column name = "SUM(A)">21</column>
</item>
</PivotSet>') columns 
  name varchar2(100) path 'column[@name eq "B" ]/text()', 
  sum  number path 'column[@name eq "SUM(A)" ]/number()')
```

or by column postion

```
columns 
  name varchar2(100) path 'column[1]/text()', 
  sum  number path 'column[2]/number()'
  )
```